# Adding the "Produces" filter globally in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a REST Api using ASP.NET Core. I want to force the application to produce JSON responses which I can achive decorating my controllers with the "Produces" attribute. Example:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

But according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting the filter can be applied globally, but I can't really figure out how.

Is there anyone out there that could provide a simple example of how to apply the "Produces" filter globally?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The linked documentation tells it already, you just have to *read* carefully **and follow the link** ;)

> See [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) to learn more, including how to apply filters globally.

and when you follow the link you find an sample:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(SampleActionFilter)); // by type
        options.Filters.Add(new SampleGlobalActionFilter()); // an instance
    });

    services.AddScoped<AddHeaderFilterWithDi>();
}
```

In your case:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6.0, this is done with the AddControllers method:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(...);
});
```